# how to enforce inclusion rules in ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model, validation

I'm new to rails and I have a question on how best to enforce custom rules on my model associations.

For example, suppose I have:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
end
```

and now suppose that I only want to allow the `Organization.people << Person.new(...)` command to succeed if the new `Person` object is compatible with the other `people` that were previously added to the `Organization`. This would entail running a validation check across all the existing elements of `Organization.people` and deciding whether the new `Person` could be added or not.

It seems to me that I can do this by overriding all the `Organization.people` assignment operators (such as `<<` and `=`) and putting my validation logic in the override routine.

Is this best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could put a validation in the Person class. It would run a test against the other people in self.organiation.people.  I don't know if I would override the << on the has many relationship only because if you decide to create a person like Person.new(:organization => some_org) your << override would not get used.  If the validation lives on the Person class, it would get exercises no matter how you create the person.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, the decision really belongs in the Organization class. The Person class should not decide who makes it in to the Organization - that should be up to the Organization. Therefore, I think I will take your suggestion of triggering the validation from the Person class (i.e. by validating against :organization) but the validation will simply delegate the decision to Organization by calling a decision function in the Organization class. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I agree. You could easily have a validate :blah, then do a delegate :blah to the oranization.